# fold/wrapping effect with CSS

Tags: css, sass

How do you do the fold/wrapping effect for [this website](http://www.wlu.edu/)?...is there a technical term for it?

I know I can easily go to view-source to check on the CSS, but I can't figure out which part does the little folding part (I circled in orange).
Or if I knew the tech term, I could look it up.

[image]

Comment: You can do that easily with a [CSS triangle](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

Comment: @kei, thanks for the tip!...the biggest hurdle to finding solutions is not knowing the proper terminology!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the page in Chrome, you'll see it uses the following CSS selectors, which apply to the banner itself:

```
#slider .slider .slide .box.top-right:before {
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid #303030;
    bottom: -6px;
    right: 0;
}

#slider .slider .slide .box:before {
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
```

So basically it's saying "before the div for the banner, put a pseudo-element with blank content with absolute positioning". And then also, the top selector is more specific, saying to position it on the bottom right, with a special border trick that gives the little triangle.

edit: people sometimes call that trick "CSS triangles".

Comment: The base trick woukld be *triangles*, but the overall effect is sometimes called *ribbon*